# How can I give discord users with a specific role limitations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to limit the actions of users on a discord server that are interacting with a discord bot for a specific time.
As an example:
The user with the role "user" can only press a button 10 times in a day (24h). A other user with the role "user2" can press the button 20 times in a day. After that the user gets a message that he reached the daily limit. How can I do that in js?

I couldn't find anything about the topic.

Comment: have a database, increment a count and a last updated timestamp. use that information to reset the count if the current time is the next day, and to ignore extra button presses based on the role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a function that will check whenever the member is rate limited and another where you add 1 to the limit. I decided to merge those 2 functions so you can call it when someone runs a command and it will add 1 to the limit.

I assume that this is for a guild (since its role-based). So you must give a GuildMember as a variable of the function.

```js
let Limits = {};

function isRateLimited(member){
    let Today = new Date();
    Limits[member.id] ??= {Date:Today,Rate:0}; //if Limits[member.id] has no value, then it will set it as an object.
    if(!(Limits[member.id].Date.getDate() == Today.getDate() && Limits[member.id].Date.getMonth() == Today.getMonth() && Limits[member.id].Date.getFullYear() == Today.getFullYear())){//if not today, then reseting the rate limit & setting date as today.
        Limits[member.id].Date = Today;
        Limits[member.id].Rate = 0;
    };
    if(member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "ROLE 1") && Limits[member.id].Rate < 20){ //if member has a specific role and his rate limit is lower than authorized, then adding 1 to the rate limit and returning true
        Limits[member.id].Rate++;
        return true;
    }else if(member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "ROLE 2") && Limits[member.id].Rate < 10){ //if member has a specific role and his rate limit is lower than authorized, then adding 1 to the rate limit and returning true
        Limits[member.id].Rate++;
        return true;
    }else if(member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "ROLE 3") && Limits[member.id].Rate < 5){ //if member has a specific role and his rate limit is lower than authorized, then adding 1 to the rate limit and returning true.
        Limits[member.id].Rate++;
        return true;
    };
    return false; //the member is rate limited (he has reached the limit), it will return false;
}
```